# Are there homeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} / S_n$ into $\mathbb R^k$ where $k$ grows more slowly than $k\sim O(m^2 n)$?

Tags: general-topology

I am a physicist, not a mathmo, and I am working with some objects which are multisets (i.e. sets able to contain repeats) containing $n$ elements, each of which is a vector in ${\mathbb R}^m$. I.e. one could perhaps notate one such multiset as follows:
$$M(n,m,V)= \{   \vec v_1, \vec v_2,\ldots,\vec v_n \} $$ wherein each $\vec v_i$ is some point in $\mathbb R^m$, and where $\vec v_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ column of some matrix $V\in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$.  I am not certain of the name and/or correct notation for the space in which such multisets $M(n,m,V)$ lie, but I suspect it is some kind of quotient-space which I will notate like this: $$\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} / S_n$$ in which $S_n$ is meant to be the permutation group of order $n$ -- which in this case permutes the columns of $V$.   (But as I am a lowly physicist, not a mathmo, I may be inadvertently misusing that notation somehow!)

I have been trying to map such objects **continuously and losslessly** into a real Euclidean space (or subset thereof) which has a dimension which is as low as possible. This is so that I can (among other things) represent any such multiset $M$ numerically in a computer as an array of real numbers $A(M)$ safe in the knowledge that $(A(M_1)=A(M_2))\iff(M_1=M_2)$.

My understanding is that mathematicians would say that: **I am trying to find homeomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} / S_n$ into $\mathbb R^k$ (or some subset thereof) for some $k\ge mn$ where $k$ is as small as possible.**

For me, the smaller $k$ is the better -- at least as measured by the leading behaviour of $k$ as a function of $m$ and $n$.  Clearly $k$ can never be smaller than $mn$ as homeomorphisms are continuous.  Currently the best encoding I can find which  achieves the objectives set out above (see below) sees $k$ scale as follows:
$$k \sim O(m^2 n).$$

**What I would like to know is whether there are better encodings which scale less badly with $m$ (e.g. which scale like $k\sim O(mn)$ or $O(mn\log m)$ would be better!).  Or whether there are good books I could read which would help me learn more. Or if there are no mappings that scale better than the one I already found, then it would be good to have some insights into why that mapping can't be bettered.**

To keep the question short, I should probably stop here.

However, in case it helps for me to provide some extra context, I can report that the simplest-to-describe $k\sim O(m^2 n)$ encoding I have found by experimentation and trial-and-error is as follows:
$$
f: M(m,n,V) \mapsto (a_{1121}, a_{1122}, a_{1123}, \ldots, a_{2(m-1)mn}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m(m-1)n}
$$
where for any $1\le i < j \le m$ and for any $1\le k \le n$ we have
$$
a_{1ijk} = \Re(z_{ijk})\text{, and}
\\\\
 a_{2ijk} = \Im(z_{ijk})\phantom{\text{, and}}
$$
where
$$
z_{ijk}=\sum_{t=1}^n \left( V_{it} + i V_{jt} \right)^k.
$$
The principle behind this encoding is that it maps every pair of rows of the matrix $V$ to a list of $n$ complex numbers, which are then themselves encoded (up to a reordering) as the roots of an order-$n$ polynomial over the complex numbers -- this being a polynomial whose coefficients can themselves be encoded (among other ways) through the use of [power-sum symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial) . (Aside: there are some redundancies in this encoding ... so it is possible to reduce $k$ to something slightly smaller than $m(m-1)n$ however the leading term is still $k\sim O(m^2 n)$ so I will not discuss that small reduction here.)

Comment: One definitely can embed in the Euclidean space of dimension $<2nm$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan : your tantalizing comment interests me.  I'd very much like it if what you say is true -- since it "feels" like the complexity of the problem is $O(mn)$.   But I've not managed to find an $O(mn)$ embedding myself that was continuous and bijective, so I would be interested to hear more about why you think one should be possible.

Comment: I will write an answer later but it is a very general result on embeddings of simplicial complexes, a simplicial analogue of Whitney embedding theorem for manifolds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some terminology. Let $X$ be a topological space. Then $n$-th [symmetric product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_(topology)) of $X$, denoted $SP_n(X)$, is the quotient of $X^n$ (the $n$-fold product of $X$ with itself) by the action of the symmetric group $S_n$, which acts by permuting components of tuples $(x_1,...,x_n)\in X^n$. On general grounds, if $X$ has topological dimension $m$, then $X^{n}$ has topological dimension $nm$ (more precisely, the Lebesgue covering dimension) and its quotient by $S_n$ has the same dimension. There is a general theorem in topology  which states that every locally compact metrizable topological space of dimension $N$ can be embedded in ${\mathbb R}^{2N+1}$. But, likely, you do not care about such general embeddings and, besides, for $SP_n({\mathbb R}^m)$ one can do better than $2mn+1$. It is instructive to first look at the cases $m=1, m=2$:

1. $m=1$. Then we are considering the quotient of ${\mathbb R}^n$ by $S_n$ which acts by permuting the components of vectors. The quotient space  ${\mathbb R}^n/S_n$ is homeomorphic to
   $$
   Q=\{(x_1,...,x_n): x_1\ge x_2\ge ...\ge x_n, x_1,..., x_n\in {\mathbb R}\}. 
   $$
   The space $Q$, of course, embeds in ${\mathbb R}^n$ and one cannot do better than this.
2. $m=2$. It is convenient to identify ${\mathbb R}^2$ with the complex plane. Then $SP_n({\mathbb C})$ is the set of unordered $n$-tuples of complex numbers $\{z_1,..,z_n\}$. For every such tuple there exists (unique up to multiplication by a nonzero complex number) complex polynomial $p(z)$ of degree $n$, whose roots (counted with multiplicity!) are exactly $z_1,...,z_n$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that this polynomial is *monic*, i.e. has
   the form
   $$
   p(z)= z^n + a_{n-1}z+...+a_0. 
   $$
   The space of monic polynomials is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb C}^n$ (by recording the $n$-tuple $(a_0,...,a_{n-1})$). Hence, $SP_n({\mathbb C})$ is homeomorphic to ${\mathbb C}^n$ which, of course, embeds in ${\mathbb R}^{2n}$ and one cannot do better than this.

Starting from the case $m=3$, the symmetric product $SP_n({\mathbb R}^m)$, unfortunately, is not a topological manifold (not even a manifold with boundary). However, it can be triangulated and becomes an (infinite) simplicial complex of dimension $N=mn$. Every countable simplicial complex $C$ of dimension $N$ embeds (as a subcomplex) in ${\mathbb R}^{2N+1}$. Here is the construction. First, enumerate the vertices of $C$ as $v_1, v_2,...$. The vertex set of $C$ is denoted $C^0$. Next, define an arbitrary map $f: C^0\to {\mathbb R}^{2N+1}$ such that
$$
\lim_{i\to\infty} ||f(v_i)||=\infty. 
$$
Then extend $f$ linearly (more precisely, by an affine map) to each simplex in $C$: This extension (again called $f$) is unique. The image of a simplex is, of course, again a simplex and, if we choose $f$ generically, then $k$-dimensional simplices in $C$ are mapped onto $k$-dimensional simplices in ${\mathbb R}^{2N+1}$. The key fact is that if $\Delta^i, \Delta^j$ are simplices of dimensions $i, j$ in ${\mathbb R}^{i+j+1}$ then **generically** they are disjoint (i.e. if we perturb them a bit they become disjoint). Since the maximal dimension of a simplex in $C$ is $N$ and the target space is chosen to have dimension $2N+1$, by choosing $f: C^0\to {\mathbb R}^{i+j+1}$ to be generic, we ensure that for any pair of simplices $c, c'$ in $C$ we have
$$
f(c)\cap f(c')=f(c\cap c'). 
$$
From this, it follows that $f: C\to {\mathbb R}^{2N+1}$ is an embedding. This gives you a simplicial embedding
$$
SP_m({\mathbb R}^n)\to {\mathbb R}^{2nm+1}
$$

One can do better. Let $V$ denote the vector space ${\mathbb R}^n$. Then $V^m$ splits as the direct sum of two linear subspaces:
$$
diag(V^m) \oplus W, W=\{(x_1,...,x_m)\in V^m: x_1+...+x_m=0\} 
$$
and $diag(V^m)=\{(x,...,x), x\in V\}\subset V^m$. This direct sum decomposition is invariant under the permutation action of $S_n$ and $S_n$ acts trivially on the first factor. Hence,
$$
V^m/S_n = diag(V^m) \times W/S_n,
$$
where $W$ is a vector space of dimension $mn-n$. The quotient $W/S_n$ again can be triangulated and, as I explained above, embeds in ${\mathbb R}^{2(mn-n) +1}$. Hence,  $V^m/S_n$ embeds in
$$
{\mathbb R}^n \oplus {\mathbb R}^{2(mn-n) +1}= {\mathbb R}^{2(mn-n) +1+n}.$$
Hence, $SP_n({\mathbb R}^m)$ embeds in ${\mathbb R}^k$,
$$
k= 2mn -n+1.
$$
One can do even better than this, but I stop here.

Comment: Thank you for this exceptionally clear and helpful answer.  I appreciate the care you have taken (or appear to have taken) to pen an answer that includes sufficient context and illustrations to make it approachable to someone outside the field (like me) without compromising on the details needed to make the answer precise.  Thank you again!